# How can I align Polymer paper-tabs to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I'm trying to build my new personal website right now, and to avoid using huge gobs of JS for what I'm planning, I'm trying to align the paper-tabs that form the site navigation to the right side of the screen, but still with a margin on the right. I can't really use CSS margins because the tabs would only look right on my screen. The site is at http://adueppen.github.io/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put an element with `flex` attribute in the toolbar, it will fill the space where it is inserted. You can use this to right-align your tabs, like so:

```
<core-toolbar class="tall animate">
  <span class="bottom" flex></span>
  <paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="0" class="bottom indent" style="width: 300px">
    <paper-tab name="home"><p>Home</p></paper-tab>
    <paper-tab name="projects" ><p>Projects</p></paper-tab>
    <paper-tab name="blog"><p>Blog</p></paper-tab>
    <paper-tab name="about"><p>About</p></paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>
</core-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the paper-tabs in `<div horizontal end-justified layout style="width:100%">`.

Checkout this reference on using [layout attributes](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html).

Comment: Sort of looks right, but now tabs aren't really on the bottom. See website.

Answer (score 0):

In Polymer 1.6, the `paper-toolbar` is split with an element of `class="title"`.

The "title" element will be the last item on the left side, and the elements after it will be right-justified.

From the Polymer `paper-toolbar` demo:

[image]

```
<paper-toolbar>
  <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
  <span class="title">Title</span>
  <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
  <paper-icon-button icon="add">+</paper-icon-button>
</paper-toolbar>
```

If you don't want a title, just use a blank `div`:

```
<div class="title"></div>
```